# Question closed without good reasons and mainly referencing a closed one?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, behavior

Today I asked this question: [How to get rid of CS8601 the most elegant way (most appropriate way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973999/how-to-get-rid-of-cs8601-the-most-elegant-way-most-appropriate-way)

It was closed.

No reason given. Like very often when the question cannot be answered easily. But, yes, I shouldn't have said "The most". I re-wrote my question like that: [How to get rid of compilation error "CS8601 Possible null reference assignement" without disabling error message in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974350/how-to-get-rid-of-compilation-error-cs8601-possible-null-reference-assignement)

Then my second question was also closed with a reference the the first one. Why? How's that possible?

I would like to bring your attention to few points:

- I don't understand how my second question can be closed referencing my first closed question.
- Why close a very good question? Why are there people out there that can vote down? Why they should have those rights?
- Many of my recent questions are closed, and very quickly. That is new from a year or 2. Most of them are appropriate but very complicated to answer. That's why I ask them. But as soon as people can't answer, they vote to close. They do not understand half of it, but they vote to close. That is a very popular behavior these days and it is very frustrating. I really think that nobody should vote to close without giving a good reason (anonymous, I don't care). But how can you improve yourself this way? Why would you want to use this site if you take a lot of time to compose something the best you can and someone closes it, leaving the writer with no reason to understand what's wrong?

Comment: strictly speaking, a reason was most certainly given, we don't have any close options that don't give a reason.

Comment: A reason absolutely was given for the closure of that question, it's seeking our opinion, on the best way to aomplsh something.  "What's the best way to get rid of the compilation error .." and "Then my second question was also closed with a reference the the first one?????? Why ????" - Because once a question is closed it should be improved not asked again.

Comment: How do you know the people who vote to close can't answer and don't understand half of it? Also, if people can't understand your question, *shouldn't* it be closed?

Comment: "Many of my recent questions are closed, and very quickly." - [Your question history says otherwise.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452845/eric-ouellet?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=1).  If you are deleting your questions, instead of clarifying and improving the questions, that will eventually present problems asking new questions.

Comment: There is no "I don't understand" close reason

Comment: I've found that coming to the question of why a question was closed with a bit of humility is usually the best course of action. Remember; you're coming to this site to ask a question of volunteers. They are giving up their time freely to help you and everybody after you that has the same question. They absolutely do not owe you that time or an answer. The only thing they owe you is the respect and dignity you offer them. Think about that before you assume they are closing your questions because they "cannot be answered easily". Perhaps there is something in the question that warrants closure?

Comment: "Elegant" is an an opinion.  What is elegant to one person is not elegant to another.  100% easy close for being an opinion based question.

Comment: I'm wondering, would a merge be applicable/ valuable in the case, or would it be overkill?

Comment: @zcoop98 I have asked for that through a custom flag on the second question.

Comment: (@zcoop98 It might be a little overkill, but at this point having the first question reopened and the answer undeleted and moved without moderator intervention would be a lot of trouble, so I guess it doesn't hurt to ask.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events, as best as I can gather:

1. You asked a question.
2. That question [got closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66973999/timeline).

   - You misunderstood, or didn't see, the close reason, and found this (justifiably) confusing and frustrating.
3. [Someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973999/how-to-get-rid-of-cs8601-the-most-elegant-way-most-appropriate-way#comment118386449_66973999) that your question might've been closed because of your focus on "the best/ most elegant way", also mentioning that it was closed due to being opinion-based (which was accurate).
4. You [appreciated the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973999/how-to-get-rid-of-cs8601-the-most-elegant-way-most-appropriate-way#comment118386699_66973999), heeded it, and asked a new question.

   - This second question was worded better and more on-topic than the first as a result.
5. Two hours later, the [second question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66974350/timeline) as a duplicate of the first.

   - At this point, you'd added an answer on that second post, and it had received more activity than the first.

I think there are a few things to note here.

First, I understand your frustration. Having a question that you've put time and effort into get closed is never fun, and this case in particular sounds *very* frustrating. Ranting on Meta... rarely leads to positive results, but I understand why you felt frustrated and driven to do so.

Second, I'm not going to say that the first question shouldn't have been closed. I can't speak for the close voters, but I strongly suspect that the suggestion was accurate, and that your post's focus on "best way," and your title, which included "most elegant way" and "most appropriate way," lead them to see the question as opinion-based, and to vote to close accordingly. Opinion-based posts, including posts which focus on "best practices" or "elegance," are [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I'm personally not convinced that the essence of your post really is opinion-based, especially given that your second post is far more objective with just those wording changes, but I can see why others might have read it differently.

Third, and maybe most importantly, you should know that *you violated protocol* by posting a new question after your first was closed, instead of editing it. **This is the main issue you ran into here.** According to our help center page "[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)":

> Stack Exchange is collaboratively built, maintained, and moderated by the community. If you see a question and you disagree with the stated [reason of its closure](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/closed-questions), you should **first try to edit the question** to improve it as much as possible. Read the close notice and any comments carefully to address concerns raised there. Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening.

On Stack Overflow, when a question is closed, the way to remedy that closure is by **editing** the question, *not* by posting a new one. This is why your second question was closed. The fact that it was the better, more on-topic version of the question is simply an unfortunate twist (this isn't usually the case when a question gets posted twice by the same person).

The best way forward now is likely to delete the second question, and edit your first. Add in or replace the content of your first question with the body from your better, second question, and the first one will get sent into the reopen queue. [@BSMP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4076315/bsmp) has some more great suggestions in [their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406609/question-closed-without-good-reasons-and-mainly-referencing-a-closed-one/406617#406617) for improving your question overall, which should also help it get reopened.

If you feel that your self-answer from the second question is valuable, then I'd probably copy that over from the second post to your first one as well. Note that copying an answer from one place to another is not something anyone should normally do outside of these circumstances, but an actual merge to maintain your single answer might be a little overkill in this case.

---

As a final note... I noticed that you've been around Stack Overflow for over a decade. Posting a duplicate when a question gets closed is a commonplace, honest mistake for new members of the community, but you've asked over 100 questions at this point, over the last 10 years. I'm frankly unsure what to make of this. I mean no disrespect to you or your experience, but I'd encourage you to get to know a little bit more about how this site works, and about why it's set up the way that it is in terms of votes and closures and such. It could help you avoid frustrating pitfalls like this one in the future!

Comment: Nobody, and when I say nobody, I'm really close to it, read the rules of a site. I did not and none read them or read them fully. I learned with the time like most of us. I made a lot of mistake and there was users like you and sometimes like me who put peoples on the right track by commenting, not by voting down without comment. I already complain about it and still do. I still maintain that what I say here is the way the world run, run in real life.

Comment: I made a mistake. I agree. I try to fix it the best way I though. I already try to correct an answer but was never put back online and I was so frustrated. It was almost the exact same circumstance than here. But nothing happen. My question was just killed without any good reason. I will take time to edit my initial question because I should have known the rules. But there is something that really does not work here. Asking for the "best way" should not be closed automatically. It is not an opinion by default. There is implied standard rules that govern coding and thatis what it refer too.

Comment: By the way, there is no way to ask a complicated question at stackoverlfow without being vote down and/or reveiving a vote to close. There is NO way to ask it without reveiving any of these. That kills!!!

Comment: Complicated question absolutely are possible.  I reject the notion that complicated question are always downvoted

Comment: @EricOuellet "_Nobody, and when I say nobody, I'm really close to it, read the rules of a site. I did not and none read them or read them fully._" - Well, I did. I think it's the correct way to join an established community. To me, it shows respect - and it avoids a lot of friction.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is:

1. Delete the second question.
2. Rewrite the first so it's not asking for the best/most or anything opinionated. Essentially just copy/paste what you have for the second question into the first. Except:
3. When you add the error message that's currently in your 2nd version, add it as text instead of a screenshot.
4. Also include the points of clarification in the comments on the 2nd question, like where you say you're using .Net Core 1.1. Go ahead and put all of that in the question too.

Comment: I never had the time to modify my question before it was closed. So I wrote another one because there is so many incompetent programmers out-there unable to understand the idea behind a question and who does not know the langage itself and its new features. I took the time to rewrite my question adequatly with taking car of each and every words choosen (calculating that english is not my first langage) but it finally was still closed again. I want the second to be re-open because there is no good reason on earth to close it. How can you close a question refering a closed one?

Comment: I can't remove my downvote. I just want to say thank you. You are right and in accordance to this website rules. I was frustrated because you asked me to delete my second question which was to my opinion the right one. Having to re-write the first one appears to me as real big time lost because it is already at 3 downvotes and nobody read thoses. Although I did not want to do it. I did it and took a chance to have it back (which is so frightening to not having it back online). You need to a  great courage to  endure all the hassle it could give when you already have all answers from a friend.

Comment: Sorry I cannot remove my vote down. That is another frustration I have with stackoverflow... You can't change your mind. You cannot adjust your comment after 5 minutes either if you find some little mistakes. Grrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

I fully stand behind zcoop98's answer. However there is one aspect here that is left untouched and I think it should not be swept under the rug.

*Should your question have been closed as opinionated to begin with?*

Short answer: no.

It was apparently done based on some trigger words. "the best/most elegant way", something which people like to add to questions for at least two reasons in my experience.

1. Essentially they're saying "no hacks please, give me a proper solution" - this is unnecessary to say, Stack Overflow's quality rules and content rating already safeguard that for you. Sure someone might post a hack answer but that answer is likely to be downvoted and you are free to ignore it.
2. Because they're perfectionists and they don't stop to think about what those words really mean in the context of a site like Stack Overflow. It's so easy to ask for it, it's darned near impossible to provide it. How do you prove something is the best / most elegant? Who is qualified to dictate that? No, we provide working solutions. Whether something is elegant enough or not is up to you personally to decide, you get to pick and choose which answer you like the most. Any other person reading your question and the answers will do the same using their own judgement. We have a quality voting system for a reason.

Essentially whatever the reasoning for saying such things, it's fluff that can be edited out of the question and it'll still be the same question but just without any trigger words. This is exactly the case for this question, if you edit out all the lingo relating to "the best" or "the most elegant" it'll turn into a very Stack Overflow-compatible question about getting rid of an error that is caused by a new language feature. And that is ultimately what you are after, aren't you?

So I would like to stress to people who are about to hit the close vote button to mark something opinionated: *Don't close if it can easily be edited by anyone*. The entire sequence of events detailed in zcoop98's answer could have been avoided if only someone had assumed the best and made a little effort. But at the end of the day... you are still dealing with human beings, so the best that can be done is to take care with your choice of wording right from the get-go to avoid a mess. So TL;DR:

Should your question have been closed? No.

Could it have been worded better? Definitely yes.

In the end, it's always a shared responsibility to make things go smoothly.

Comment: So your saying the author could edit out the unnecessary fluff and the question would have automatically been placed in a queue to be reopened and it would have been?  Because certainly asked for the best approach was seeking an opinion, as it was written, and most likely was directly responsible for the question being closed.

Comment: @SecurityHound there is no need to reopen if it was never closed to begin with. Don't close if you can edit it was the point.

Comment: Who is responsible for editing out the fluff then, because both the author’s questions were closed, so someone would have to do it